# Scrollbar amchart legend

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

[image]

I want a scrollbar for a label when the label more then the chart height. I mentioned in image where I want scrollbar. Actually sometime I have many labels therefore.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Documentation here: 
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-legend-in-an-external-container/#Making_legend_scrollable

You need to put the Legend into an external div thats inside a wrapper div.

The Div Structure:

```
<div id="legendwrapper">
<div id="legenddiv"></div>
</div>
```

Putting the legend in the external div:

```
var legendContainer = am4core.create("legenddiv", am4core.Container);
legendContainer.width = am4core.percent(100);
legendContainer.height = am4core.percent(100);
```

Then you can make it scrollable by styling it like this:

```
#legenddiv {
  width: 150px;
}

#legendwrapper {
  max-width: 120px;
  overflow-x: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this with AMCharts 4

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "right"; // Positionning your legend to the right of the chart
chart.legend.scrollable = true: // Make it scrollable
```

See a full example as below :
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/eYmLvoR